# Microservices and database security

Tags: java, .net, database, security, microservices

I am new to microservices architecture. The design principle says a microservice has its own database. Should I be worried about the security of connecting to the database or the security of the communication between microservice and database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that traffic should be protected with TLS or some other method.

Microsoft lays out some thoughts an options [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/azure-security-data-encryption-best-practices#protect-data-in-transit) (even though they steer you towards MSFT products, the concepts are relevant).

> Best practice: Secure access from multiple workstations located on-premises to an Azure virtual network.
>
> Detail: Use site-to-site VPN.
>
> Best practice: Secure access from an individual workstation located on-premises to an Azure virtual network.
>
> Detail: Use point-to-site VPN.
>
> Best practice: Move larger data sets over a dedicated high-speed WAN link.
>
> Detail: Use ExpressRoute. If you choose to use ExpressRoute, you can also encrypt the data at the application level by using SSL/TLS or other protocols for added protection.
>
> Best practice: Interact with Azure Storage through the Azure portal.
>
> Detail: All transactions occur via HTTPS. You can also use Storage REST API over HTTPS to interact with Azure Storage and Azure SQL Database.